# How to factor this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I was trying to factor this polynomial:

> $x^3 + x^2 - 16x + 20$

There are four options in this question:

1. (*a*) It could be factored in the following form: $(x^2 + b)(x+c)$;
2. (*b*) It could be factored in the following form: $(x+b)(x+c)(x+d)$, assuming that $b \neq c \neq d$
3. (*c*) It could not be factored.
4. (*d*) It could be factored in the following form: $(x+b)^2  (x+c) $

Here's how I've tried to do it:
I've tried to factor by grouping the x, therefore I've obtained:
$x(x^2 + x - 16) + 20$. Now, I've put the $x$ and the $20$ together:
$(x+20)(x^2 + x - 16)$.
Then, I've tried to factor the second term: $(x+20)(x-16)(x+1)$. So, the answer would be "b", according to this algorithm.

I've completed the test (it's a simulation for the admission test I'm going to do), I submit the answers, and I've noticed that this question isn't correct.

Comment: Doesn't it factor as $(x-2)^2(x+5)$?

Comment: You cannot factor out the $(x+20)$ as you have done. There is no common factor of $(x+20)$ between $x^2 + x -16$ and $20$. 
Hint on what to do: Guess at a root of the polynomial and perform synthetic division.

Comment: Theorem: every polynomial to be factorized in a homework question has small, integer roots :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Fernis pointed out in the comments,

> You cannot factor out the $(x+20)$ as you have done. There is no common factor of $(x+20)$ between $x^2+x−16$ and $20$.

Using the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), you can know that the possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm2, \pm4, \pm5, \pm10, \pm20$.

Through inspection and polynomial/synthetic division, you can get $(x-2)^2(x-5)$, as @saulspatz said. Therefore, (d) is your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest to try is (d), because it says that the polynomial has a double root. We will look for a root of the derivative and check if it cancels the polynomial.

$$3x^2+2x-16=0\iff x=2\text{ or }x=-\dfrac83.$$

Now $p(2)=0$, bingo !

Comment: Good solution, but not sure if OP understands calculus

Answer (score 1):

This one is easy to factor. Let's see how.

Start by plugging in $x=0,1,-1,2$ and so on.

You will find by inspection that $x=2$ is a zero of the polynomial. Therefore,$(x-2)$ is its factor.

Now factor the polynomial in such a way that $(x-2)$ gets common.

$$x^3+x^2-16x+20$$
$$=x^3-2x^2+3x^2-6x-10x+20$$
$$=x^2(x-2)+3x(x-2)-10(x-2)$$
$$=(x-2)(x^2+3x-10)$$
$$=(x-2)(x^2+5x-2x-10)$$
$$=(x-2)[x(x+5)-2(x+5)]$$
$$=(x-2)^2(x+5)$$